# Running PyTorch on M2 Mac - Ventura 13.2.1

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network

Does anyone know how to enable/force PyTorch to use the GPU on the new macbooks? It looks like the NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit does not support Ventura and I cant find anything about it online. Any Ideas?

This is the code where the error is thrown (Not all of it, just a portion):

```
input_dim = 6  
hidden_dim = 256
layer_dim = 3
output_dim = 4
seq_dim = 16

lr = 0.0001
n_epochs = 150
iterations_per_epoch = len(trn_dl)
best_acc = 0
patience, trials = 300, 0

model = LSTMClassifier(input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, output_dim)
model = model.cuda()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
sched = CyclicLR(opt, cosine(t_max=iterations_per_epoch * 2, eta_min=lr/100))

print('Start model training')


train_loss_list = []
valid_loss_list = []
for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
    
    train_loss = 0.0
    valid_loss = 0.0

    for i, (x_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(trn_dl):
        model.train()
        # x_batch = x_batch.cuda()
        x_batch = x_batch
        # y_batch = y_batch.cuda()
        y_batch = y_batch
        out = model(x_batch)
        loss = criterion(out, y_batch)
        opt.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()
        sched.step()
        
        train_loss += loss.item() * x_batch.size(0)
    train_loss_list.append(train_loss)
    
    model.eval()
    correct, total = 0, 0
    for x_val, y_val in val_dl:
        x_val, y_val = [t.cuda() for t in (x_val, y_val)]
        out = model(x_val)
        preds = F.log_softmax(out, dim=1).argmax(dim=1)
        total += y_val.size(0)
        correct += (preds == y_val).sum().item()
    
        loss = criterion(out, y_val)
        valid_loss += loss.item()*x_val.size(0)
    valid_loss_list.append(valid_loss)

    acc = correct / total

    # Printing training/validation statistics 
    print('Epoch: {} \tTraining Loss: {:.6f} \tValidation Loss: {:.6f}'.format(
      epoch, train_loss, valid_loss))

    if acc > best_acc:
        trials = 0
        best_acc = acc
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'data/output/model/best_{best_acc:2.2%}.pth')
        print(f'Best model saved with accuracy: {best_acc:2.2%}')
    else:
        trials += 1
        if trials >= patience:
            print(f'Early stopping on epoch {epoch}')
            break
print("-----------------------\nTraining is done!!")


path_training_loss = "data/output/training_loss_modify.csv"
np.savetxt(path_training_loss, 
          [str(train_loss) for train_loss in train_loss_list], 
           delimiter ="\n",  
           fmt ='% s') 
path_valid_loss = "data/output/valid_loss_modify.csv"
np.savetxt(path_valid_loss, 
          [str(valid_loss) for valid_loss in valid_loss_list], 
           delimiter ="\n",  
           fmt ='% s')
```

Here is the error:

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[51], line 14
     11 patience, trials = 300, 0
     13 model = LSTMClassifier(input_dim, hidden_dim, layer_dim, output_dim)
---> 14 model = model.cuda()
     15 criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
     16 opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:905, in Module.cuda(self, device)
    888 def cuda(self: T, device: Optional[Union[int, device]] = None) -> T:
    889     r"""Moves all model parameters and buffers to the GPU.
    890 
    891     This also makes associated parameters and buffers different objects. So
   (...)
    903         Module: self
    904     """
--> 905     return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniconda/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:797, in Module._apply(self, fn)
    795 def _apply(self, fn):
    796     for module in self.children():
--> 797         module._apply(fn)
    799     def compute_should_use_set_data(tensor, tensor_applied):
    800         if torch._has_compatible_shallow_copy_type(tensor, tensor_applied):
...
    244     # doing the initialization; when they get the lock, they will
    245     # find there is nothing left to do.
    246     if is_initialized():

AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

Tried multiple "fixes" online and tried to download the NVIDIA CUDA toolkit but ran into an error of it no longer supporting Ventura